# jquery reinitialized while loading external page using load(). Jquery lib is also added in the external page.

Tags: jquery

I dont have control over the code in the external page, so I am not authorised to remove the jquery lib from the external page. Because of this, the original page plugins are lost.

To be more clear,Page A has below code after including jquery.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.ezpz_tooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.contextmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.dynDateTime.js"></script>
```

Page B has just jquery.js added.  Page B is a standalone page too

Now loading page B in Page A using load() to a div in Page A causes the context menu, tooltips functionality loss in Page A.

I understand the reason that the jquery will be reloaded and because of this, its reinitialized. Is there a way I can prevent it or reset the state of jquery to -before the load condition?-

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running `jQuery.noConflict()` after Page B is loaded.

Comment: thanks. That really helped. Also with examples from jquery forum here [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)